# Print a string after a for loop that prints in stderr

Tags: python-3.x

I need to print a string only after my loop (that's printing in stderr) is finished...like this:

```
for i in range(0, 1000000):
   print(i, file=sys.stderr)

print("The for loop in done.")
```

P.S. I already tried using:

```
import time
time.sleep(<ex. 5sec.>)
```

Comment: Your problem is probably solved by simply flushing `stderr` at the end of the loop. This will cause the terminal (or whatever is actually printing `stderr`) to write all text currently buffered. There is no other way to orchestrate stderr/stdout the way you want, they are fundamentally unsynchronized.

Comment: @user2722968 thank you I understood the problem...I'm working on it

Comment: @user2722968 with sys.stdout.flush() it's working, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

In Python **3.7+** there is an update to use `asyncio.run`. [Docs here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run).

In python **3.6.x and earlier** 
[Coroutines and tasks](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/asyncio-task.html)

```
import asyncio

async def do_thing():
   for i in range(0, 1000000):
      print(i, file=sys.stderr)

def finish_thing():
   loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
   loop.run_until_complete(do_thing())
   loop.close()
   print("The for loop is done.")
```

And then you just call `finish_thing()`

Comment: I tried your resolution, but it still doesn't work...it prints me "The for loop is done." after printing in stderr 990545

Comment: @Mr.Sleepy Does it continue to print the the values for >=990546 after printing "The for loop is done."?

Comment: Yes, but now I'm thinking that maybe it could be PyCharm...probably cleaning the buffer can help...I'm still suspicious...Thanks for your help @deedub

Comment: @Mr.Sleepy I used it in PyCharm's python console when I tested.